# Change the height of an html element when a button gets clicked with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a login.php page. The page contains php and html. When the login button gets clicked it will either log me in and Forward me to the welcome page or output "your Password or username is invalid". I want to change the height of an element. Sadly this doesen't work because php is reloading the page(witch makes sense). I heard i can make it work with Ajax.
Does somebody know how to do that?

Button:

```
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Log In" onclick="ausgabe();">
```

Javascript:

```
function hardgainer(){
    var gainheight = document.getElementById('gain')
    gainheight.style.height ="220px";
    document.getElementById('gain').innerHTML = gainheight;
}

function ausgabe(){
    document.getElementById('button') = 
        hardgainer();
}
```

Comment: If you want to know how to use `AJAX`  and `PHP`, you need to search on Google, read about it and try to implement it, and if you stuck we can help you. But, if you need to know how to just change the height of an element, you need to edit your question!

Comment: So you need to "submit" in order to determine if the username/password are invalid correct?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? `document.getElementById` does return an element in the DOM. I do not understand your `ausgabe` function purpose.

Comment: @bradbury9 oh i got more functions. i output them all via ausgabe makes the code readable

Comment: @Charles380 just realised not really

Answer (score 0):

You are **submitting** the form and therefore the page reloads. You should change the `type` to `type="button"` and then you can make something like this:

```js
function hardgainer(){
    var gainheight = document.getElementById('gain')
    gainheight.style.height = "220px";
}

document.getElementById("gbutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  hardgainer()
})
```

```css
#gain {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input id="gbutton" type="button" value="Log In">

<div id="gain"></div>
```